# Use phpunit with Laravel and Spatie

Tags: laravel, phpunit, laravel-permission

I try to use phpunit with Laravel and Spatie but i have a issue.

I have this test :

```
 public function testBasicTest()
    {

        $user = User::where('id', 2)->first();

        $response = $this->actingAs($user, 'api')->json('POST', '/providersList', [
            'database' => 'test'
        ]);

        $response->assertStatus(200);   
    }
```

But i have a 401 error

```
  Expected status code 200 but received 401. Failed asserting that 200 is identical to 401.
```

I have this in web.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api','role:Admin']], function() {

    Route::post('/providersList', 'ProviderController@index');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a common issue when doing testing, I can assure you that the cause of this error is because of your authentication because of 401 HTTP error code, check if the acting user has role admin

Comment: I check by ```dd($user->hasRole('Admin'));``` and it's return true

Comment: try using postman and manually hit that api, you should see output of your error

Answer (score 0):

To get a better error output, add this to the top of your test function

```
 $this->withoutExceptionHandling();
```

It should give a better idea of what the issue is.